# Travel to Serbia with UK type C visa

Tags: visas, uk, pakistan, serbia

I am a Pakistani and we need an embassy visa to enter Serbia. I also hold a UK type C visa right now and I was wondering if I could go to Serbia during this pandemic from Pakistan on the basis of this UK visa.

Comment: When are you planning to travel and how long do you intend to stay? When does your UK visitor visa expire?

Comment: @Traveller does it matter?  Does Serbia have a unilateral visa exemption for people holding UK visitor visas?

Comment: @phoog I think it may do from a quick look at Timatic, with the length of stay allowed depending on the visa validity period.

Comment: My visa is valid till September, 2021 and I intend to stay for only 11 days, so I can go to UK. I wish to travel by the end of May.